# how to apply device camera view as background to a opengl surface in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, camera

Basically I am having a 3D object to be rendered using open gl. But the background of the 3D object should be a Camera View. so that the 3D object will fit in to the camera view shown by the device camera.

Currently Im using the following code to achieve it.

```
cameraView = new CameraView(this);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams generalLayoutParam = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

addContentView(mainscreen, generalLayoutParam);

_glSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) mainscreen.findViewById(R.id.surfaceviewclass);
_glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
_glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
_glSurfaceView.setRenderer(r);
```

But the problem with this code is, I need to Capture the 3D object and camera view behind the 3D object  as a single image. I am doing it by getting the parent of these views and getting the drawing cache of that view. But, the camera view is coming as black area.

Is there a way to embed the cameraview in to open glsurfaceview or a way to take screen shot along with cameraview properly??

Comment: Ive not played much with android and dont know how surface are compositing, but you may stream your video on a GL texture and draw a full screen quad behind your model

Comment: If your question is not about the display, but only about screen capture, then you can use the traditional [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), and convert the preview (YUV) into bitmap manually, not depending on the SurfaceView.

Comment: @AlexCohn : Yeah i just need to capture the surface view along with camera's preview as background. Can u help me with some link for converting it?

Comment: I usually call [setOneShotPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)) and convert the (one) YUV buffer to bitmap; I know how this bitmap is located on the screen and how it is overlapping with other views from analyzing the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit your APP to API >= 11, it's easy to [use SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) which can be rendered by your OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But im new to open gl, so can u please elaborate on your point? And if im right wat u r saying is, I need to give the opengl surfaceview to be the background of cameraview and the take a capture screen from camera view. Im I rite?

Comment: No, you use the same GL surface to display the camera preview (the texture you defined in `setPreviewTexture()`) and also for your 3D object. You can learn from an [example by Romain Guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/U5RXFGpAHPE) and the following discussion.